# need Fluidmaster 400 Fill Valve seal, can I substitute one?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

I need this seal: Fluidmaster Fill Valve Installation Kit Model 250. It's apparently only available at Home Depot which is far away. 
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Fluidmaster-Fill-Valve-Installation-Kit-250/202252982

The seal goes between the 3/8 rigid supply line and the shank (bottom end) of the Fluidmaster 400 fill valve.

My local Lowes has vinyl garden Hose Washers, but the OD is too big. An O-ring isn't big enough to be sealed by the plastic nut, because the opening in the plastic nut is oversized. It would be a major problem to replace the rigid supply tube with a flexible supply line, because the bottom end of the supply tubing is very hard to get at.

Anything I can substitute? Thanks.

---

There is another seal (which I don't need, as it's for the top of the supply valve, not the bottom). That one is sold all over, including Lowes: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Fluidmaster-Rubber-Toilet-Hardware-Kit-For-Fluidmater-400A/1000106791
For some odd reason, the seal kit that I actually do need is only sold at Home Depot, and that's even according to Fluidmaster's own website.

Comment: The washer comes with Fluidmaster fill valves, it is actually 2 washers in one: the inner cone washer (included for the dubious purpose of being a replacement for your supply line) can be separated from outer ring washer, which is seal at the bottom of the valve on the inside of your tank. If you only need a washer for supply line (you already have fill valve tank-seal washer) then I can tell you what to do, parts readily available. If you need the fill valve tank-seal washer then it's special, you will need to get one (they are available from ubiquitous on-line retailer, not just at H.D.)

Comment: Thanks very much, Jimmy. Now I understand why the washer as shown on the image looks odd, it's 2-in-1. Yes, I only need the cone washer for the supply line. After several years in place being untouched, it had somehow become deformed and started slightly leaking. What should I do? You said: "parts readily available". Where would that be? Can I take the old one to Lowes and match it up?

Comment: @Jimmy Fix-it The original equipment washer that I need to replace is like a cone washer with a ring washer attached. It looks like a hat with a circular brim that goes all the way around,

Comment: What you need is a "ballcock (5/8") x 3/8" cone washer. The "tophat" shape you see is because the cone washer has been miss-shapened by years of being squished. Any good **plumbing** shop will have it (big box may not have it). See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Before the use of flexible supply lines became common, copper tubing (sometimes plated chrome or other decorative finish) was commonly used as water supply connection between a stop valve at the wall and the plumbing fixture (e.g. faucet, toilet). This is sometimes still used in commercial applications or where needed for aesthetics.

The tubing used comes in various sizes but commonly 3/8", 7/16", and 1/2" O.D. This is *not* the same type of tubing as coiled copper refrigeration tubing (even though both are measured by O.D.) as it was supplied in straight lengths, typically 6'.

The connection method used cone washers, brass friction rings, and special nuts designed to work with the cone washers. There are many configurations possible in regards to the thread on the nut, the size of the hole in the nut, the sizing of the brass washers, and the sizes of cone washers.

Using a toilet connector as an example, a plumber would want to be able to work with any size tubing so rather than carry nuts to accommodate 3 tubing sizes he would stock a nut for toilets (5/8" ballcock thread) with a 1/2" hole. If needed for 3/8" tube he would use a brass friction ring to reduce the hole size to 3/8", then use a [5/8" to 3/8" cone washer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NP18VSO).

[image]

Conscientious plumbers always use a *beading tool* to make a raised bead on the supply tube, capturing the nut to prevent catastrophic flood (tube inadvertently pulling out of the nut).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, @Jimmy Fix-it. However, this one I have is apparently called a "cone step washer", with the shape like a hat built in. Like this: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B002H3BGB0/ref=psdc_6807163011_t1_B0066CC860      Would you expect at a local shop that I'd pay around $5 for what I need? If so, I suppose I might as well just get a whole new 400A.

Comment: You don't need that. Just use a plain ballcock (5/8") x 3/8" cone washer. They cost like 75 cents. Don't overtighten.

Comment: Thanks, again Jimmy. I'll get that. (The one you linked to at Amazon was $5 each and i saw others online the same price, btw.) Have a good day.  [Oh boy, I can't marked it solved because I'm too new. Sorry.]